# Using an int type variable in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic

When I run the following code:

```
DECLARE @FundConfigSetID INT = 1
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Correct.PolicyDetail C
            INNER JOIN config.fund f ON C.longfundid IN (f.fundid, f.longfundid)
                                     AND f.FundConfigSetID = ' + @FundConfigSetID

EXEC(@sql)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT * From Correct.PolicyDetail C
>   inner join config.fund f
>       on C.longfundid in (f.fundid, f.longfundid)
>       and f.FundConfigSetID = ' to data type int.

I'm assuming I have the syntax incorrect at

```
 and f.FundConfigSetID = '+@FundConfigSetID
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `cast` the `int` to a string type when appending it to a sql string:

```
CAST(@FundConfigSetID AS NVARCHAR(10))
```

Complete SQL:

```
DECLARE @FundConfigSetID INT = 1;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Correct.PolicyDetail C
inner join config.fund f
    on C.longfundid in (f.fundid, f.longfundid)
    and f.FundConfigSetID = ' +  CAST(@FundConfigSetID AS NVARCHAR(10))

EXEC(@sql);
```

See the docs:

### [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

> Converts an expression of one data type to another.

With your variable being an `int` value, SQL is trying to convert the rest of the SQL clause to an `int` as it believes you are trying to add the 2 values together, which is what the error boils down to. By converting it to a string type, it knows you want to append the two strings together.

To highlight the opposite, where the first string is numeric:

```
DECLARE @FundConfigSetID INT = 1;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '1' +  @FundConfigSetID

PRINT @sql
-- output = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of quick and easy options

```
DECLARE @FundConfigSetID varchar(25) = 1
```

or

```
...'+cast(@FundConfigSetID as varchar(25))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to add your variable, which is an int, to the rest of the query. Here's a quick fix which will resolve your issue:

```
DECLARE @FundConfigSetID int = 1

Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql ='SELECT * FROM Correct.PolicyDetail C
inner join config.fund f
    on C.longfundid in (f.fundid, f.longfundid)
    and f.FundConfigSetID = '+ CAST(@FundConfigSetID AS NVARCHAR(10))

Exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the int to varchar first

```
DECLARE @FundConfigSetID int = 1

Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql ='SELECT * FROM Correct.PolicyDetail C
  inner join config.fund f 
    on C.longfundid in (f.fundid, f.longfundid)
   and f.FundConfigSetID = '+ convert(varchar, @FundConfigSetID)

Exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the int to varchar, otherwise Sql server tries to implicitly cast the varchar to int:

```
'.... and f.FundConfigSetID = '+ CAST(@FundConfigSetID as varchar(10))
```